# Get Syntax error on right join postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join

Got 2 queries, the first one :

```
select SUBSTRING ("PriseNom",1,2) as "Chassis", "Date", "Time", sum("Puissance_W") as "Conso en W"
 from "vPe-Pdu"
 where SUBSTRING ("PriseNom",1,2) in ('0G','0H','0I','0J','0K','0L','0M','0N')
 group by 1,2,3
 order by "Date" desc ,"Time" desc, "Chassis" asc
 limit 8
```

outputs me 8 lines :

```
Chassis;Date;Time;Conso en W

0G;2023-08-25;11:00:01;871
0H;2023-08-25;11:00:01;1053
0I;2023-08-25;11:00:01;1147
0J;2023-08-25;11:00:01;1016
0K;2023-08-25;11:00:01;1618
0L;2023-08-25;11:00:01;1214
0M;2023-08-25;11:00:01;1666
0N;2023-08-25;11:00:01;1560
```

The second one gives me more lines :

```
select SUBSTRING ("Chassis_Nom",1,2) as "Chassis", count(*) as "Nb Part"
 from "vPower-Lpars"
 where "Date" = (current_date - INTERVAL '1 day')::date
 group by 1;;
```

```
Chassis;Nb Part

0a;130
0L;3
0H;39
0J;20
0K;24
0I;39
0M;19
0b;178
0d;46
0G;17
0N;4
0f;49
0e;17
```

So, I just want to add the 'Nb Part' column to get a unique query by the way of a JOIN USING

Tried :

```
select SUBSTRING ("PriseNom",1,2) as "Chassis", "Date", "Time", sum("Puissance_W") as "Conso en W"
 from "vPe-Pdu"
 where SUBSTRING ("PriseNom",1,2) in ('0G','0H','0I','0J','0K','0L','0M','0N')
 group by 1,2,3
 order by "Date" desc ,"Time" desc, "Chassis" asc
 limit 8
LEFT JOIN
select SUBSTRING ("Chassis_Nom",1,2)  as "Chassis", count(*) as "Nb Part"
 from "vPower-Lpars"
 where "Date" = (current_date - INTERVAL '1 day')::date
 group by 1
USING ("Chassis")
```

But I've a syntax error I don't know how to avoid (I've checked spaces between keywords) :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LEFT"
LINE 5: LEFT JOIN
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 220
```

And of course, I need to have my order and limit kept in the first query.
So, what do I miss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join has a different syntax and you need parenthesis for the subqueries

```
SELECT 
    t1."Chassis",t1."Date", t1."Time", t1."Conso en W", t2."Nb Part"
FROM (select SUBSTRING ("PriseNom",1,2) as "Chassis", "Date", "Time", sum("Puissance_W") as "Conso en W"
 from "vPe-Pdu"
 where SUBSTRING ("PriseNom",1,2) in ('0G','0H','0I','0J','0K','0L','0M','0N')
 group by 1,2,3
 order by "Date" desc ,"Time" desc, "Chassis" asc
 limit 8) t1
LEFT JOIN
(select SUBSTRING ("Chassis_Nom",1,2)  as "Chassis", count(*) as "Nb Part"
 from "vPower-Lpars"
 where "Date" = (current_date - INTERVAL '1 day')::date
 group by 1) t2
USING ("Chassis")
```